# What to do if some datetime values 'don't match format'?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

i have big data challenges using a big number of csv files. In the second column there data times and I just want to read the data.
I used

```
dt1=list1[1][1]
dt_obj1=datetime.datetime.strptime(dt1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

and after this 
`first_date=dt_obj1.date()` and it worked well. 
The Problem is that there a a few (just 10 of over a million) entries where there is just a date instead of a date time and so it doesn't match the format.
Do you have any ideas how i can just read the date in this entries (or ignore them)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library. The advantage of using this library is that you don't have to worry about the format. Its parser would automatically select the format matching your data.

```
from dateutil.parser import *
dt_1 = parse("Sat Oct 11 17:13:46 UTC 2003")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use try/catch to design the way you read, suppose you have all possible formats in a `formats` list, then you can do

```
dt = None
for format in formats:
    try:
        dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, format)
        break
    except:
        pass
```

This will ensure you only break the loop when you get the correct format, otherwise keep trying possible formats.

Otherwise you can use the external [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) library parse function [parser.parse](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse) which can parse any datetime format irrespective of the format

```
from dateutil import parser

print(parser.parse("1990-01-21 14:12:11"))
print(parser.parse("1990-01-21"))
#1990-01-21 14:12:11
#1990-01-21 00:00:00
```